# Strange behaviour of ArrayList in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, arraylist

i'm developing web app using jsf. I trying display property "brandName" of element with index 0 in ArrayList "materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList" and this property for all elements using "c:forEach".

```
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            #{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList.get(0).material.material.brandName}
            <br/>
            <hr/>

            <c:forEach
                    items="#{materialsSummaryBean.electrolyserMaterialLotList}"
                    var="item" varStatus="loop">
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        #{item.material.material.brandName}
                        <br/>
                        <hr/>
                </c:forEach>
```

In result i have absolutly randomize list of values for element with index 0:

```
ШБ-5 
ЗШБ класс 4 
МШ-39 
ЗШБ класс 4 
МШ-39 
КПД-400И 
ШБ-5 
МШ-39
```

For all elements in list:

```
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        КПД-400И
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        ШБ-5
                        МШ-39
                        ЗШБ класс 4

                        <hr />

                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        МШ-39
                        КПД-400И
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        ШБ-5
                        МШ-39

                        <hr />

                        МШ-39
                        КПД-400И
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        КПД-400И
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        ШБ-5
                        МШ-39

                        <hr />

                        ШБ-5
                        ЗШБ класс 4
                        МШ-39
                        МШ-39
                        ШБ-5
                        КПД-400И
                        МШ-39

                        <hr />
```

And i don't have any idea what is it and what is the problem.

MaterialsSummaryBean method "getElectrolyserMaterialLotList":

```
public List<MaterialLotSummaryData> getElectrolyserMaterialLotList() {
    MaterialLotFilter materialLotFilter = new MaterialLotFilter();
    materialLotFilter.setElectrolyserId(id);
    return materialService.getMaterialLotByElectrolyserId(materialLotFilter);
}
```

And "getMaterialLotByElectrolyserId" method:

```
public List<MaterialLotSummaryData> getMaterialLotByElectrolyserId(MaterialLotFilter materialLotFilter) {
    Long electrolyserId = materialLotFilter.getElectrolyserId();
    if (electrolyserId == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Electrolyser id cannot be null.");
    }

    TypedQuery<Unit> queryUnit = em.createQuery(
            "select u from Unit u where u.electrolyser.id = :selectedElectrolyser", 
            Unit.class)
            .setParameter("selectedElectrolyser", electrolyserId);


    List<Unit> unitList = queryUnit.getResultList();
    HashSet<MaterialLot> materialLotList = new HashSet<MaterialLot>();

    HashMap<Long, Double> materialLotUsageMap = new HashMap<Long, Double>();

    for (Unit unit : unitList) {
        MaterialLot currentMaterialLot = unit.getMaterialLot();

        if (currentMaterialLot == null) continue;

        materialLotList.add(currentMaterialLot);


        Double usage = unit.getActualMaterial().getAmount();
        if (!materialLotUsageMap.containsKey(currentMaterialLot.getId())) {
            materialLotUsageMap.put(currentMaterialLot.getId(), (usage == null) ? 0 : usage);
        } else {
            if(usage == null) continue;
            Double currentUsage = materialLotUsageMap.get(currentMaterialLot.getId());
            materialLotUsageMap.put(currentMaterialLot.getId(), currentUsage + usage);
        }
    }

    List<MaterialLotData> result = mapper.createList(materialLotList, MaterialLotData.class);

    MaterialLotSummaryData summaryData;
    ArrayList<MaterialLotSummaryData> summaries = new ArrayList<MaterialLotSummaryData>();
    for (MaterialLotData materialLot : result) {
        if (materialLotUsageMap.containsKey(materialLot.getId())) {
            summaryData = new MaterialLotSummaryData();
            summaryData.setId(materialLot.getId());
            summaryData.setAcceptanceDate(materialLot.getAcceptanceDate());
            summaryData.setLotNumber(materialLot.getLotNumber());
            summaryData.setMaterial(materialLot.getActualMaterial());
            summaryData.setNumber(materialLot.getNumber());
            summaryData.setManufacturer(materialLot.getManufacturer());

            Double usage = materialLotUsageMap.get(materialLot.getId());
            summaryData.setUsage(usage);
            summaries.add(summaryData);

            materialLotUsageMap.remove(materialLot.getId());
        }
    }

    return summaries;
}
```

Comment: Show us the bean code. Otherwise it's a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service method is called each access of `electrolyserMaterialLotList` and the list prepared by accessing to database and doing same operations again even  for single item access. You should avoid doing so. Basically, you can use null check in getter method.

```
public List<MaterialLotSummaryData> getElectrolyserMaterialLotList() {
    if(electrolyserMaterialLotList == null)
    {
          MaterialLotFilter materialLotFilter = new MaterialLotFilter();
          materialLotFilter.setElectrolyserId(id);
         electrolyserMaterialLotList  = materialService.getMaterialLotByElectrolyserId(materialLotFilter);
    }
     return electrolyserMaterialLotList;
}
```

Comment: Basically OP should avoid lazy getters as much as he can. Moving initialization to (post) constructor methods / action (listener) methods should always be preferred.